# How to get the starting time - execution time of the submitted job script file in slurm system with bash shell script code?

Tags: bash, slurm

How can I get the starting time OR execution time of the submitted job script file in SLURM system with a bash script?

Comment: `echo $SECONDS` will show how long since the current bash shell was started.

Comment: I like to start my job scripts with `echo Hello from $(hostname) on $(data)` and end them with same with "Bye". For resource consumption, you can put `time` ahead of the main command your job file is launching. Now, what you're asking for ought to be provided by `sstat`, somehow, but I couldn't figure out how to get the right output. But you should be able to call it from within a job script, if your cluster is configured for it.

Comment: I echo the `date` and `time` to a separate log.txt file that give unique times for each task in an `sbatch` job array. I experience the same error as @joanis when using `sstat`, so I feel more comfortable keeping these separate logs in case of change in slurm tool behavior or loss of access to slurm.

Answer (score 0):

**I prefer this way** you can display the job information at the end of the file which includes the running time

```
squeue -j $SLURM_JOBID
```

another way

you can put the time at the beginning and at the end then count by yourself

```
date
```

- for the end file time  (put `date` at the end of the file)

OR

you can display your all jobs which running now with their duration :
for all your jobs

```
squeue -u <Username>
```

[image]

Comment: the code should be in sbatchfile.sh and you don't need to put echo before these code lines